# Avoid multiple windows of the same kind

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

My goal is to have an interactive bar chart. I want to open a window containing a text. This shall happen when the user clicks on one of the bars. I started playing around a bit. In the following example, if you click on the left bar a window containing a text pops up. The problem I have, I only want to have the window opening once. So if you click a second time on the left bar, I don't want to open a second window. Therefore my question, how can I check if the window already exists and avoid multiple windows of the same kind. I already found a post regarding this topic, but I do not understand the solution, which was only explained  poorly.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
def on_press(event):
    cont,att = rect[0].contains(event)
    if cont == True:
        win = tk.Tk()
        label1 = ttk.Label(win, text ="Test1").grid(column=0,row=0)
        label2 = ttk.Label(win, text ="Test2").grid(column=0,row=1)
        label3 = ttk.Label(win, text ="Test3").grid(column=0,row=2)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = [1,2,3]
y = [10,20,5]
rect = ax.bar(x,y)



test = rect[0].figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You can add a variable and set it to True when creating your window and when destroying set variable to False. Or use singleton.

Comment: You‘re right, maybe that‘s the easiest way to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a solution for my problem. Like MediaEU said, I use a variable which I set to true or false. However, one important "trick" is to use the method state().
If a main window is open, state() returns 'normal'. If a main window is closed state() throws an exception. Took me - as a starter - quite some time to figure it out.
Here is my suggestion:

```
class info_window:
    def __init__(self, rect): # has an argument rect, for a specific bar in your plot
        self.rect = rect
        self.win_open = False
        self.state = 'normal'
        self.temp = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def label(self):
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.win, text ="Test1").grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.win, text ="Test2").grid(column=0,row=1)
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.win, text ="Test3").grid(column=0,row=2)

    def __call__(self, event):
        cont, att = self.rect.contains(event) 
        try:                    # here is the "trick", in case window was closed self.win.state() throws an exception
            self.win.state()
        except:                 # setting win_open to False ensures that a window can be opened again
            self.win_open = False
        if cont == True:    
            if self.win_open == False: # if window does not exist, create it
                self.win = tk.Tk()
                self.label()
                self.win_open = True # as long as window is open, you can't create it again
```